# OpenCV Code Sample Error

Tags: c, opencv, runtime-error

I have written the following Code Sample that is supposed to create a peculiar-looking gradient and save it to a file specified by the user:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

static IplImage *image = 0;

void main() {
   char path[1024];
   int x, y;
   CvScalar scalar;

   scanf("%s", path);
   image = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640,480),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);

   for (y = 0; y < 480; y++) {
      for (x = 0; x < 640; x++) {
         scalar = cvGet2D(image, x, y);
         scalar.val[0]=(unsigned char)(x + y);
         cvSet2D(image, x, y, scalar);
      }
   }

   cvSaveImage(path, image, 0);
}
```

I compile it using: `` gcc opencv.c -o opencv `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -lm `` and everything seems to be OK. However, during runtime (input: "sample.png"), I get the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (index is out of range) in cvPtr2D, file /builddir/build/BUILD/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp, line 1797
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /builddir/build/BUILD/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/array.cpp:1797: error: (-211) index is out of range in function cvPtr2D

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Any help, please? Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: Anyway, rather than using this indirect access, I'd recommend you to try the direct access using a C++ wrapper (see http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00053000000000000000). Your code will be more efficient and understandable. :)

Comment: You Mean Mat? By the way, that's exactly the Site I'm using as a reference! lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cvGet2D and cvSet2D uses [row,column] convention like many other functions in opencv.

For further readings:
http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! :D That's exactly what I was messing up!
The fact, though, that I didn't get a "Segmentation Fault" error is kind of surprising to me, as I was getting out of the bounds of the Image! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `cvGet2D` and `cvSet2D` function take the row as the first argument, and the column as the second argument: you have the x and y arguments the wrong way round. Hence you are going outside the image. The call should be:

```
cvGet2D(image, y, x);
```